# How to solve a greedy regular expression

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a problem with regular expression in PHP.

This text should be handled:

```
Start Text1
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
End Text1
Start Text2
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
End Text2
```

I would like to add <ul> and </ul> to the <li> lines.

I try this, with this patter:

```
(?!<\/li>)\s*(<li>.*</li>)\s*(?=<li>|)
```

But gives something like this:

```
Start Text1
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
End Text1
Start Text2
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
</ul>
End Text2
```

... the "End Text1" and "Start Text2" also included. So I prefer to get this result:

```
Start Text1
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
</ul>
End Text1
Start Text2
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
</ul>
End Text2
```

How can I do this?

I tested this here: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/sHs#tab-preg-replace

Comment: The problem is that the `.*` inside `<li>.*</li>` is capturing everything from the first `<li>` to the last `</li>`. My first guess is to make it non-greedy - use `.*?`, but I won't be surprised if it then gives you the `<ul>` for each `<li>` instead of each block...

Comment: I'm the worst guy ever when it comes to regular expressions, but I managed to shovel this together on RegExr: https://regexr.com/4guhk    - The strange thing is that it seems to work fine here, but I can't make it work with php preg_replace...

Comment: Hum, works on https://regex101.com/r/hoB4a9/1  All I have to change is escape the `/` in `</li>`, and it's matching twice, just like you'd want. Don't know if it'll work the same in php, though.

Comment: This works: `(?!<\/li>)(\s*<li>.*?<\/li>\s*)(?!\s*<li>)`

Comment: Confirmed, might as well post it as an answer. You can see it in action here: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/sHL#tab-preg-replace

Comment: @joanis: Thank you, that's the answer!

Comment: @Andrew do you know how to make phpliveregex.com interpret `\n` in the replacement pattern as a newline? I expect it works in regular code if you double quote the replacement pattern, but not in that web page, where single quote interpretation seems to apply.

Comment: @joanis I couldn't manage to make \n work outside of that site either, but I hacked it up with some good old php end of line constants...: https://3v4l.org/vvSDn

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the link. Yes, you can use `\n`: `"\n<ul>\n$1\n</ul>\n"` works correctly. The trick is to use double quotes instead of single ones.

Comment: Updated my answer with better handling or newlines.

Answer (score 1):

**Fixing the regex**

This regular expression works:

```
(\s*<li>.*?<\/li>\s*)(?!\s*<li>)
```

Explanation:

- `.*?` asks the regex to match as little as possible between `<li>` and `</li>`, so that it stops as soon as there is text not within an `<li>`;
- I escaped the `/` in the second instance of `</li>`, as you had already done in the first instance;
- `(?!\s*<li>)` says the next bit of text cannot be another `<li>` - needed because otherwise `.*?` above makes it match each `<li>` line separately;
- the initial `(?!<\/li>)` doesn't actually do anything, so I removed it.

**Nicer handling of newlines**

On the Live Regex web site, I was not able to insert newlines where I wanted to.

In php proper, you can use

```
preg_replace('/\s*(<li>.*?<\/li>)\s*(?!\s*<li>)/smi',
   "\n<ul>\n$1\n</ul>\n", $input)
```

or

```
preg_replace('/(\s*<li>.*?<\/li>\s*)(?!\s*<li>)/smi',
   "\n<ul>$1</ul>\n", $input)
```

to get nicer results. The key is to put the replacement pattern in double quotes.

**Handling indented input better**

If the input was indented, you might also consider something like this:

```
preg_replace('(\s*)(<li>.*?<\/li>)(\s*)(?!\s*<li>)/smi',
   "$1<ul>$1$2$1</ul>$3", $input)
```

this will put `<ul>` and `</ul>` at the same indentation level as the first `<li>`, and keep the surrounding text at the indentation it had beforehand.

But obviously none of this is really important given all these spacing variants won't change the interpretation of the resulting HTML.